# Manage Delegate out UIViewController class

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I would like to understand what would be the best way to implement a delegate out `UIViewController` class

How can I manage the delegate using `controller: UIViewController` parameter of my function in AuthManager?

These are the two classes I'm working with .. I show you small examples to make you understand

```
 class StartController: UIViewController {

    @objc private func presentAuthFacebookController() {
        AuthManager.signInWithFacebook(controller: self)
    }
}
```

---

```
class AuthManager {
static func signInWithFacebook(controller: UIViewController) {

    let loginManager = LoginManager()
    loginManager.logIn(permissions: [.publicProfile, .email], viewController: controller) { (result) in

        switch result {
        case .cancelled : print("\n AuthFacebook: operazione annullata dall'utente \n")
        case .failed(let error) : print("\n AuthFacebook: \(error) \n")
        case .success(granted: _, declined: let declinedPermission, token: _):


            let authVC = ExistingEmailController()

            authVC.delegate = // ?????? (controller)

            UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(authVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally don't think `StartController` should know about/conform to `ExistingEmailControllerDelegate`. But if you really want, you can declare `controller` as a composition type:

```
static func signInWithFacebook(controller: UIViewController & ExistingEmailControllerDelegate) {
    ...
    authVC.delegate = controller
```

---

In my opinion, the whole point of having a `AuthManager` is to *create a layer of abstraction* on top of `ExistingEmailController`, and to *encapsulate the logic* of authentication. Therefore, `StartController` shouldn't know, or care, about `ExistingEmailControllerDelegate`. It only knows about `AuthManager`.

`AuthManager` should be the delegate of `ExistingEmailController`, which implies that `signInWithFacebook` should not be static, and `AuthManager` can have an `AuthManagerDelegate` that `StartController` conforms to:

```
class AuthManager : ExistingEmailControllerDelegate {
    weak var delegate: AuthManagerDelegate?

    func signInWithFacebook(controller: UIViewController) {

        ...

        let authVC = ExistingEmailController()

        authVC.delegate = self

        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(authVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func someMethodFromExistingEmailControllerDelegate() {
        delegate?.someMethod() // delegating it self.delegate, which StartController conforms to
    }
}

protocol AuthManagerDelegate : class {
    func someMethod()
}

 class StartController: UIViewController, AuthManagerDelegate {

    var authManager: AuthManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        authManager = AuthManager()
        authManager.delegate = self
    }

    @objc private func presentAuthFacebookController() {
        authManager.signInWithFacebook(controller: self)
    }

    func someMethod() {
        // write here the code that you would have written in someMethodFromExistingEmailControllerDelegate
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support.. Your suggestion seems much more suitable and clean to me but at this point I ask you .. The AuthManager class is invoked when the user (in StartController) clicks on the Facebook button .. If I use the AuthManagerDelegate delegate where I point the action of the button? `facebookBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(presentAuthFacebookController), for: .touchUpInside)`

Comment: @kAiN You'd create a property in `StartController` called `authManager`, initialise it in `viewDidLoad`, set `authManager.delegate` to self, and in the button action, do `authManager.signInWithFacebook(controller: self)`.

Comment: @kAiN I've added more code to illustrate what I mean. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes Yes I was already trying to implement everything ...: D you were very kind ... it's really clear! Thanks for all

Comment: Hi sorry, so far with the delegate I have not had a problem .. but I don't know why now if I present a `ViewController` with `NavigationController` from `StartController` when I dismiss this new viewController the delegate does not work .. it does not receive any input ... where am I going wrong..

Comment: @kAiN you should probably ask a new question. Remember to include a [mcve] in the new question, and if you like, a link to this question.

Comment: hello Sweeper ... if you have two free minutes can you give me your opinion on my question? Thanks always for your kindness 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60858797/delegate-not-responding-after-present-a-new-viewcontroller-from-another-class